# Lock location services (off) on android 5.1.1

Tags: applications, 5.0-lollipop, geolocation, location-services, android-x86

Is there a way to lock location services (keep it off) on android 5.1.1? Like with restrictions on iphone for example. I'm looking for a simple way to do this. A way to disable it permanently is also fine. Thanks